# Выборка случайной не использовавшейся записи

Tags: mysql

Есть большая база (1млн записей).

Мне необходимо выбрать случайную запись, которая уникальна для определенного ключа (текст) и принадлежит определенному пользователю.

Структура таблицы выглядит примерно так:

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idx` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `data` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_idx` (`idx`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Поле `idx` нужно для "рандомизации" выборки.

Поскольку у MySQL нет типа данных "массив", мне в голову пришло 2 возможных решения.

1. Сделать 2 таблицы, одна - с данными, вторая - с информацией об использованных данных.
2. Сделать таблице с данными текстовые поля `owners` и `used_keys`, в которых хранить информацию, разделяя её неким разделителем.

В первом случае я создал 2 таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE `data_owners` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `owner` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY_KEY(`id`, `owner`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `data_used_keys` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `key` varchar(32) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY_KEY(`id`, `key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Запрос выглядел так:

```
SELECT id, data FROM data JOIN data_owners USING(id) LEFT JOIN data_used_keys USING(id) WHERE owner = 1 AND key IS NULL ORDER BY idx LIMIT 10000, 1;
```

или так:

```
SELECT id, data FROM data WHERE id IN(SELECT id FROM data_owners WHERE owner = 1) AND id NOT IN(SELECT id FROM data_used_keys WHERE key = 'some_key') ORDER BY idx LIMIT 10000, 1;
```

Работал этот запрос крайне медленно (50% данных "принадлежали" пользователю 1, остальные 50% - пользователю 2).

Во втором случае было сделано 2 поля. И владельцев и ключей может быть много, потому я выбрал тип `MEDIUMTEXT`. Данные выглядели примерно так:

```
| id |  data  | owners |  used_keys  |
|  1 |  test1 | ;0;1;  | ;some_key1; |
|  2 |  test2 | ;0;2;  | ;some_key2; |
```

Запрос выглядел так:

```
SELECT id, data FROM data WHERE owners LIKE '%;1;%' AND used_keys NOT LIKE '%;some_key2;%' ORDER BY idx LIMIT 10000, 1;
```

Второй вариант работал значительно быстрее, чем первый, однако работал все равно *ОЧЕНЬ* медленно.

Я заметил, что в данном случае MyISAM отработал в десятки (а то и сотни) раз быстрее, хотя и не так быстро, как хотелось бы. Двадцатитысячная запись выбиралась почти секунду. Однако MyISAM не подходит, т.к. мне нужно получать 100% уникальную запись, а в нем нет транзакций.

Что можно сделать в данном случае?

Comment: Эмъ... Тема у вас "Выборка случайной не использовавшейся записи", а в теле вопроса у вас описаны тормоза конкретных запросов. Отвечая на тему, можно предложить `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` (если после фильтрации осталось мало записей, иначе все будет тормозить) , либо где-нить в коде генерируете случайное число и выбираете по нему (например, первый меньший id). По медленным запросам я бы порекомендовал почитать что-нибудь типа [этого](http://debian-help.ru/web-servers/mysql-indexes-explain-profiling/).

Comment: @BOPOH, я не описывал тормоза конкретных вопросов, а лишь описал те способы, которые я использовал, дабы мне их не предлагали. `ORDER BY RAND()` будет работать крайне медленно. У меня 1млн записей. Вариант с "меньшим `id`" и так был использован, только в качестве `id` выступал не Primary Key. В статье, которую предложили Вы - решением является добавление индекса. В моем случае это невозможно, т.к. у меня в `WHERE` выборка по полям типа `TEXT`.

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND()` даже на 20М работает нормально, если выборка возвращает мало записей (сортировка идет последней, поэтому не важно сколько записей было изначально, важно сколько получилось в результирующем наборе). Про "меньший id" имелось ввиду следующее: для вашего первого варианта первым запросом выбираем `min(id)` и `max(id)` по интересующим условиям, генерируем случайное число в этих пределах и следующим запросом выбираем запись, которая "меньше-или-равно" этому случайному числу. Т.к. выборка идет по id (который PK), то скорость будет высокой

Comment: А сейчас у вас вроде как основная проблема в том, что вы делаете `LIMIT 10000, 1`. Т.е. чтобы получить одну запись, необходимо перед этим обработать 10К записей. Если выборка без лимита будет не быстрой, то с лимитом будет еще дольше. Я поэтому ссылку и привел - не чтобы вы индекс добавили, а чтобы посмотрели что именно тормозит. Может стоит mysql использовать tmpfs и запросы взлетят? Или немного с настройками поиграться? Без профилирования (и понимания того, что именно тормозит) трудно оптимизировать (у вас может `idx` без индекса).

Comment: @BOPOH, `ORDER BY RAND()` не подходит, т.к. может быть такое, что пользователь владеет всеми записями и ни одна из них не использовалась (т.е. фильтрация вернет все записи в таблице). Выше я указал, какой вид имеет таблица. Как можно заметить - индекс на idx есть. Хотя Вы правы, `ORDER BY idx` крайне сильно (более чем в 100 раз) тормозит запрос (интересно почему, ведь поле проиндексировано). Изменив запрос на `SELECT MIN(id), MAX(id) FROM data WHERE owners LIKE '%;1;%' AND used_keys NOT LIKE '%;some_key1;%'` отработало значительно быстрее, но все равно долго.

Comment: `tmpfs` использовать не получится, т.к. сервер работает на Windows Server 2012. Настройки были установлены при помощи MySQL Installer. MySQL под себя выделил порядка 8 гб ОЗУ.

Comment: Если честно, то не очень понятны вот эти ваши ничего не значащие used_keys и прочие data... То, что вы шифруетесь, усложняет понимание вашей проблемы. Предполагаю, что индексы в первом варианте просто не используются. pk - составной, а соединение идет по id только. в итоге fullscan. \ Второй вариант проигрывает идеологически: парсить строки можно, но это вариант не для скорости.

Comment: @YuraIvanov Я не шифруюсь. Это реальный вид таблицы. `used_keys` - это использованные "ключи" для этой записи. Как я и говорил, уникальность нужно обеспечить по ключу.

Comment: @YuraIvanov, так здесь же id - первый в pk, поэтому индекс все равно должен использоваться. Другое дело, что если фильтрация возвращает много записей (судя по `LIMIT 10000, 1`), то mysql может забить на индексы, чтобы избежать беспорядочного чтения с диска и читать все данные с диска последовательно

Comment: @BOPOH да, первичный индекс по двум полям проигрывает фулскану. mysql не станет такой индекс использовать, если не указать явно. по хорошему там нужны просто индексы на каждое из полей (вполне возможно хватит и одного для этого запроса). и смотреть надо естественно план, мы вот опять тут не знаем в каких таблицах что лежит и в каком количестве, несмотря на "я не шифруюсь".

Comment: @YuraIvanov, в таблице `data` лежит 1 миллион записей. При использовании метода 1 в таблице `data_owners` лежит информация о том, какой пользователь имеет доступ к каким записям в `data`. На данный момент в ней 3 миллиона записей для пользователей `0` (владеет 100% записей), `1` (владеет 50% записей), `2` (владеет другой половиной записей). В таблице `data_used_keys` лежит информация о том, какие ключи для какой записи из `data` были использованы. На данный момент там 1 миллион записей. Для 2 способа данные те же, но желат они в текстовых полях и разделены разделителями.

Answer (score 1):

> MyISAM не подходит, т.к. мне нужно получать 100% уникальную запись, а в нем нет транзакций.

Это очень характерное заблуждение. Люди очень часто путают транзакции с блокировками, не понимая, что для чего нужно.

Транзакция гарантирует целостность записей. Она дает гарантию, что у нас либо изменились все нужные записи, либо ни одной.

А для уникальности нужны блокировки. В майисам вполне себе есть блокировки, на уровне таблиц. Если мы таки уверены в том, что отработаем выдачу кода быстро, то лочим таблицу на чтение, берем нужный код, записываем его в юзанные и отпускаем таблицу.

Comment: Я знаю о блокировках на уровне таблиц, но для данной задачи блокировки на уровне таблицы крайне нежелательны. Если у меня запрос будет выполняться, скажем, 250мс и 20 параллельных пользователей попытаются получить данные для разных ключей - то последний пользователь получит информацию аж через 10 секунд.

Answer (score 0):

Речь про вариант с отдельными таблицами.
Сначала запросы надо сделать одинаковыми с точки зрения возвращаемых результатов (возможно у вас там опечатка, в реальности тестируете правильные запросы, тем не менее). Первый запрос должен выглядеть так:

```
SELECT d.id, d.data 
FROM data d 
  JOIN data_owners dow on d.id = dow.id
  LEFT JOIN data_used_keys dk on d.id = dk.id and dk.key='some_key'
WHERE 
  dow.owner = 1 
  AND dk.key IS NULL 
ORDER BY d.idx 
LIMIT 10000, 1;
```

Надо сразу смотреть план. Если таки первичные ключи используются (вполне вероятно), а для сортировки индекс по `idx`, то уже неплохо.
Далее идет шаманство с индексами. Попробовать поменять порядок полей в первичном ключе `data_used_keys`. Попробовать добавить таки индексы на каждое поле в `data_used_keys` (и в data_owners попробовать тоже). Использовать hint'ы для проверки эффективности каждого из индексов (`force index`) - чем меньше записей будет отфильтровано индексами, тем соответственно будет быстрее все работать.

Запросы отличаются порядком выполнения. В первом  порядок join'ов определяется используемым индексом, во втором будут зависимые подзапросы.
Еще один вариант второго запроса такой:

```
SELECT d.id, d.data 
FROM data d 
WHERE 
  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
          from data_owners dow 
          WHERE 
            dow.owner = 1 
            AND dow.id = d.id) 
  AND NOT exists (SELECT 1 
                  FROM data_used_keys dk 
                  WHERE 
                    dk.key="some_key" 
                    AND d.id=dk.id)
ORDER BY idx 
LIMIT 10000,1;
```

ЗЫ удобнее всего анализом запросов заниматься в dbForge Studio for MySQL (бесплатная для некоммерческого использования), там можно в одной табличке смотреть сравнение `show profile` и `show variables` для нескольких запросов.
ЗЗЫ серебряной пули нет, ее надо искать, все будет зависеть от упорства и характера выбираемых данных.

Comment: Потестировал эти варианты (без `LIMIT 10000`). Не смотря на то, что `EXPLAIN` говорит, что везде используются индексы - выборка для "далеко лежащих" данных выполняется крайне медленно (на моем пк уже 10 минут прошло, а запрос еще не выполнился).